# Check constraint whether the date from one table (column) fits to another date from another table (column)

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Lets assume I have two tables as the following ones.

```
create table contract(
 c_ID       number(1) primary key,
 c_name     varchar2(50) not null,
 start        date not null,
 end          date not null,
 d_ID       number(1) null,
 constraint fk_discount_ID
 foreign key(d_ID) references discount(d_ID)
);

create table discount(
 d_ID   number(1) primary key not null,
 d_amount decimal(4,2) not null,
 valid_from    date,
 valid_until   date
);
```

Now I would like to add a constraint that checks if the discount is valid at the start date of the contract. For example, a contract started at the 1st of May 2015 and and a discount is only valid to the 30th of April 2015, which could not be applied to the aformentioned contract.

How could I do this constraint?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like Oracle?

Comment: Yes Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: No, "SQL Developer" is an application for accessing (mainly) Oracle databases; the DBMS is "Oracle".

Comment: This should be handle from code during insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't perform such complex validation using constraints unfortunately.

While there is a way to use a combination of materialized views **and** constraints (see [my blog](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html)) in reality we don't normally do that as it could have adverse performance implications.

Triggers are an option, but I would avoid them as they are hard to get right such that they always work correctly in a multi-user system.

That leaves the most common method (in my experience): building PL/SQL APIs for your transactions that enforce the business rules so that instead of simply inserting a row in `contract` the application calls the API like this:

```
contract_api.create_contract 
   ( p_name => :name
   , p_start => :start
   , p_d_id => :d_id
   ...
   );
```

The API validates the business rules before inserting, so that this call might fail with an exception like:

```
ORA-20001: Discount not valid on contract start date
```